# How to search for at least one of two groups in Python Regex, when also looking for a third group that is a must?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to use regex in order to find missused operators in my program.

Specifically I'm trying to find whether some operators (say %, $ and @) were used without digits flanking their both sides.

Here are some examples of missuse:

```
'5%'
'%5'
'5%+3'
'5%%'
```

Is there a way to to that with a single re.search?

I know I can use + for at least one, or * for at least zero, 
but looking at:

```
([^\d]*)(%)([^\d]\*)
```

I would like to find cases where at least one of group(1) and group(3) exist,
since inserting % with digits on its both sides is a good use of the operator.

I know I could use:

```
match = re.search(r'[^\d\.]+[@$%]', user_request)
if match: 
    return 'Illegal use of match.group()'

match = re.search(r'[@$%][^\d\.]+', user_request)
if match: 
    return 'Illegal use of match.group()'
```

But I would prefer to do so with a single re.search line.

And also - when I use [^\d.] does this include the beginning the end of the string? Or only different chars?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind to assert what is before and what is after is not a digit:

`(?<!\d)[@$%]|[@$%](?!\d)`

That will match:

- `(?<!\d)` Negative lookbehind to check what is on the left is not a digit
- `[@$%]` Character class, match one of `@`, `$` or `%`
- `|` Or
- `[@$%]` Character class, match one of `@`, `$` or `%`
- `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead to check what is on the right is not a digit

For example:

```
match = re.search(r'(?<!\d)[@$%]|[@$%](?!\d)', user_request)
if match: 
    return 'Illegal use of match.group()'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x8TeDq/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/quvg9S)

`[^\d.]` Matches not a digit or a literal dot. The `^` inside a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) negates what it contains. But if it is the first character of the string that is not a digit or a dot then it will match.

Comment: Thank you! It works :)
Regarding the literal dot - It was also something I wanted to allow.